# Rails AJAX partial without submitting form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

I'd like to create a page where there are two columns:

| Form to create a pizza | Suggested Pizzas |

As you use the form on the left column to create your pizza, the column on the right starts suggesting different types of pizza you could order based on the left customization.

All of the tutorials I have found bind the reloading of the partial to the form submission, however, I'd like for the partial to reload every time an input blurs or a select is changed.

Is there an easy way to do this with Rails?

I'd like to just grab the un-submitted `@pizza` object and send that to the partial every time a blur event occurs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**controller**

```
def my_pizza
  @pizza = Pizza.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

**view**

**my_pizza.js.haml**

```
$('#pizza').html('#{j render(partial: 'pizzas/piza', collection: @pizzs)}');
```

**routes**

```
get 'pizza' => "pizza#my_pizza"
```

**Inside the js file**

```
$(document).on('change', 'input', function() {
  // you can create your ajax call which will call the my_pizza method in which action you want to call. 
});
```

**You can add ajax and what ever event you want to call you can call it easily and when you will call the respective method it will updated the partial file respectively**

Comment: This is pretty neat and exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you gave yourself the answer. Just attach an event listener to the keyup's on the form and submit via ajax.

```
$('form').on('blur', function() {
  // submit ajax and do something with the response here
});
```

Comment: Right, but is there an easy way to reload the partial? Or, do I have to make an AJAX call to suggested_pizzas partial, get that data, and `.html()` the response into a div on the page? I'm just wondering if Rails has an easy method for reloading the partial?